# SQL Comparison Tools

Tags: sql, comparison

Which SQL comparison tool would you recommend for SQL server database comparisons. I've been looking at [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/) and [SQL Delta](http://www.sqldelta.com/). I'd like the ability to compare and sync database schema and data.

Comment: I have only used the Redgate products and would recommend. Note the functionality you require is in 2 different products though (that can be bought together at a discount).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with Visual Studio Database edition or higher, you can do this straight inside Visual Studio.
See the following link: <strike>http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/Handling-Database-easily-with-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx</strike> (dead link)

It's been in there since VS 2005.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use the ones provided by RedGate Softwares (which you enumerated). They are reliable, easy to use and, as far as I'm concerned, very effective!

Answer (score 1):

I like [Adept SQL Diff](http://www.adeptsql.com/sql_compare_tool_overview.htm), it works really well and is easy to use.  I find it more intuitive than redcate SQL compare.  It also includes schema and data diff/sync tools whereas with redgate they are 2 differnt applications.

Answer (score 1):

I hvae used RedGate. It allows you to do the schema comparison and also data comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Devart's [dbForge Schema Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/) and [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/).